# Julia Escape Sequence Usage

Tags: escaping, julia

Hey so I'm really new to Julia and only came across it because of trying to use Julius for a Speech-to-Text Project  (http://julius.osdn.jp/en_index.php) . Everything is set up but I keep getting an "Invalid Escape Sequence" Error originating from one of the files used. Specifically, the following line:

```
write(mlf,"\#\!MLF\!\#\n")
```

Can anyone explain what the symbols after "write(mlf,...)" mean? Or have any suggestions about how to rewrite it? I'm considering rewriting the whole code in Python but don't know what that line means. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite it as:

```
write(mlf,"#!MLF!#\n")
```

i.e. remove `\` before characters that are not allowed to be escaped, `\n` can stay at it is an escape sequence indicating newline.

On the other hand if you wanted `\` to be present in a string you would need to double escape it like this:

```
write(mlf,"\\#\\!MLF\\!\\#\n")
```